# Powershell script help needed for displaying network interfaces

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, csv

I have a script [below] that returns information about the network interfaces in `.csv` format, but I also need the `InterfaceAlias` of each adapter returned; unfortunately, I cannot get `get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` to return such a value.

Can someone help?

````
$computer = "myserver.myserver.com"
get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter "IPEnabled=TRUE" -computername $computer | foreach-object {
  $_ | select-object `
    @{Name="ComputerName";     Expression={$_.__SERVER}},
    @{Name="MACAddress";       Expression={$_.MACAddress}},
    @{Name="IPAddress";        Expression={$_.IPAddress[0]}},
    @{Name="Caption";          Expression={$_.Caption}},
    @{Name="IPSubnet";         Expression={$_.IPSubnet[0]}},
    @{Name="DefaultIPGateway"; Expression={$_.DefaultIPGateway[0]}}
}| Export-Csv -path "C:\ip_addresses_PG.csv"```
````

Comment: if `get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled=true" | fl *` does not List that property, I'd take a look at `Get-NetAdapter`. You can connect to Remote Computers via the `-CimSession` Parameter.

Comment: Yes Get-Netadapter has the Select-Object InterfaceAlias as an option, but I do not know how to incorporate that into my code.

Comment: I agree with the comment.  Just replace your statement with something like `Get-NetAdapter -IncludeHidden | Select-Object -Property * |where Status -eq "Up" | select *` and select only the fields you want in the last select, write the fields you want to an object or array as  you loop through each computer in a foreach loop, and then write that to CSV when done.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Get-NetIPInterface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipinterface?view=windowsserver2019-ps) with the `-InterfaceIndex` parameter to return the `InterfaceAlias` property value and put that into an expression of the select statement.

If that doesn't suffice, you could use [Get-NetAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=windowsserver2019-ps) with the `-IncludeHidden` parameter and a `where` filter to match the index value and put that into an expression of the select statement.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE"  | foreach-object {
  $_ | select-object `
    @{Name="ComputerName";     Expression={$_.__SERVER}},
    @{Name="MACAddress";       Expression={$_.MACAddress}},
    @{Name="IPAddress";        Expression={$_.IPAddress[0]}},
    @{Name="Caption";          Expression={$_.Caption}},
    @{Name="IPSubnet";         Expression={$_.IPSubnet[0]}},
    @{Name="Alias1";           Expression={(Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex $_.InterfaceIndex).InterfaceAlias[0]}},
    @{Name="Alias2";           Expression={(Get-NetAdapter -IncludeHidden | where ifIndex -eq $_.InterfaceIndex).ifAlias}},  
    @{Name="DefaultIPGateway"; Expression={$_.DefaultIPGateway[0]}}
}
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-NetIPInterface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipinterface?view=windowsserver2019-ps)
- [Get-NetAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

  > **`-IncludeHidden`**
  >
  > Indicates that the cmdlet includes both visible and hidden network
  > adapters in the operation. By default only visible network adapters
  > are included. If a wildcard character is used in identifying a network
  > adapter and this parameter has been specified, then the wildcard
  > string is matched against both hidden and visible network adapters.
- [Where-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: `"ComputerName","MACAddress","IPAddress","Alias","Caption","IPSubnet","DefaultIPGateway"
"sysname","BC:30:5B:8E:F8:9B","x.x.x.x",,"[00000003] QLogic BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet (NDIS VBD Client)","255.255.255.0",`                                                                                                         Unfortunately "Alias" comes up empty in output

Comment: @WillMowat I made an edit and added two different expressions represented by `alias1` and `alias2` in case that resolves the issue. Let me know how it goes when you get to it.

Answer (score 0):

````
  $_ | select-object `
    @{Name="ComputerName";     Expression={$_.__SERVER}},
    @{Name="MACAddress";       Expression={$_.MACAddress}},
    @{Name="IPAddress";        Expression={$_.IPAddress[0]}},
    @{Name="Caption";          Expression={$_.Caption}},
    @{Name="IPSubnet";         Expression={$_.IPSubnet[0]}},
    @{Name="Alias1";           Expression={(Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex $_.InterfaceIndex).InterfaceAlias[0]}},
    @{Name="Alias2";           Expression={(Get-NetAdapter -IncludeHidden | where ifIndex -eq $_.InterfaceIndex).ifAlias}},  
    @{Name="DefaultIPGateway"; Expression={$_.DefaultIPGateway[0]}}```

This works, thank you.
````